# Windows 10. Routing between two networks with same ip range

Tags: windows-10

I've got a weird problem on Windows 10. I have a first local corporate network with ip range 192.168.1.X. I also connect to second open vpn corporate network additionally using cisco vpn. The second network has also 192.168.1.X ip range.

I need to use both networks, because i have few lan resoruces and few stand resources. When i'm trying to do that, the routing malforms and a can reach only one network and the other becomes unreachable. For example:
- turn openvpn off - can use openvpn resources, can't use local resources
- turn openvpn on  - can't use openvpn resources, can use local resources

Can i somehow make routing or any settings to solve that?

Comment: Impossible. Either one or the other. How should your router know what to route where? You could try setting static hostroutes if the IPs aren't the same, but that's ugly.

Comment: I doubt, that static hostroutes inside one subnet is possible on Win10

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Unfortunately it is not possible in the way you are describing / asking.**

In case you have only few IPs on the VPN you need to communicate and these IPs are not in use in your network you can try to tune the openvpn profile and "up script" for VPN to have only specific IPs routed to the VPN. As the routing it "the best fit first" once you have smaller subnet (>24) or even single host route records (32) it will be used primarily. All the rest would be handled with the "regular" 192.168.1.0/24 network you are connected on LAN.

OpenVPN offer NAT on client level so another option you have is utilize this option so even there is 192.168.1.0/24 network on the VPN you can NAT it on openVPN client level to any other subnet so it would not be in conflict.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot achieve what you want by design. In your case different subnet should be used for each network interface.